# Why have to lock archives and dpkg while doing installing apps and updates.

Tags: installation, apt, updates, dpkg, lock

Actually if we suspend any application installing in middle or suspending updates then automatically while resuming we will get some problems like

```
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

I know how to solve these things by removing lock . but i want to know why there is going to be a lock while performing updates/installation .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simply, locks are used for their original intention: To keep other processes from mucking around with installations. Imagine the following scenario:

1. Process1 is started to install `basex`, which depends on `default-jre`
2. Process2 begins to remove `default-jre`. `basex` is already in progress so it cannot be informed of this removal.
3. Process2 finishes.
4. Process1 finishes. A nonworking system exists. This is worse if the same package is installed, then removed simultaneously.

While this may be resolved by holding a per-package lock held for the package and any packages that must exist(Dependencies), I don't know why this is not done.

A similar issue can occur if there are packages that conflict. For example, one package might be installed, and another conflicting one could be installed simultaneously(as a dependency or otherwise).